# How to add a dependency to build.gradle.kts for kotlin-multiplatform (kotlin 1.3.50)?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I started a new project with kotlin-multiplatform to create a library usable on iOS and Android using this tutorial :

https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction

It seems to work fine but I wanted to add the Serialization library mentioned at the end of the tutorial (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) and I can't make it work.

The setup guide in the library is not in Kotlin DSL so I tried different things to adapt the code but without success. Here is my project gradle :

```groovy
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And now my build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}


kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SharedCode"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.13.0")

    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.13.0")
    }

    sourceSets["iosMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:0.13.0")
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets
        .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
        .binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\n"
                + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                + "./gradlew \$@\n")
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

I have no errors but I cannot use the library in my code.
Can someone please explain how to integrate this dependency or any dependency with this setup ? What do I do wrong ?

Note : I'm using Android Studio 3.5.1, Gradle 5.4.1, Kotlin 1.3.50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue.. just the version of the library.. 0.13.0 not 0.14.0. No error is thrown when you sync a wrong library version. I hope this post helps someone anyway.